# WebService (.asmx) function not showing up after copying from one pc to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a project which consists of `webservices(.asmx)`.
The point is when i copied that project from one of my computer to another and then wrote a function, what occurred was that it did not threw any error but it did not show me the new function which i wrote and showed the list of all the functions which were declared before copying.

`WebMethod` code is below:

```
[WebMethod]
public string test(string msg)
{
   return msg;
}
```

After built or rebuilt in output tab it shows:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CabSoftService, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Postcode". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2151,5): warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "MSDATASRC". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2151,5): warning MSB3293: Could not resolve dependent COM reference "7c0ffab0-cd84-11d0-949a-00a0c91110ed" version 1.0.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: published in first pc ?

Answer (score 2):

After creating a `webservice` you have to deploy in `IIS` ,the reason why the files may be missing may be the project might not have been deployed in the second system.If you have taken same project always **rebuild** and **publish** again.

Comment: is the files same ? rechecked ? project name ? project properties ?

Comment: is your project having any special references like third party ?

Comment: yeah i does which are not available on my local machine and are deployed on server...

Comment: i noticed that on built/rebuilt in the output tab it shows "========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped =========="

Comment: That is the answer you are looking for as i said BUILD & REBUILD ! With build getting failed how come !

Comment: or this may be the cause of not showing up the methods...what do you say & suggest..??

Comment: yes ! always BUILD & REBUILD ..with build fail you cannot get output..if answer was helpful you can mark.

Comment: When i built it, it shows about 6 warnings and when i swap over to output tab "Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped"

Comment: dear @HaiderKhattak it should be "0 failed"..check your code